# Why is my variable value "undefined" when I set it as a value of number input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, numbers

My HTML is the following:

```
<td class="quantity">
   <input value = "1" type="number">
</td>
```

and here is the JS code:

```
var quantity = 0;
function addItem(){
        quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0].value;
```

Basically I want the quantity variable to change to the value of the input value which I set to 1 as default. The console returns "undefined" when I check the value of quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you check the `td` element instead of the input,

`document.querySelector("input[type='number']").value;`

Comment: now I changed it to quantity = document.querySelector("quantity[type='number']")[0].value;



and I get this error: Cannot read property '0' of null

Comment: Not `quantity`, but `input` @billynotreally

Comment: @billynotreally `getElementsByClassName` retrieve an array of the elements with that class, now with `querySelector` you get the item itself (just one item), it not an array as before.
Can you mark my answer as resolved then?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var quantity = 0;
function addItem(){
        quantity = document.querySelector(".quantity")[0].querySelector("input").value;
```

You need to select the input inside the table cell.